# Php twig conversion

Tags: php, twig

Does anyone know how to convert this php to twig?

```
<?php echo isset(${'discount_value' . $customer_group['customer_group_id']}) ? ${'discount_value' . $customer_group['customer_group_id']} : ''; ?>
```

Because when i convert it into this:

```
{{ 'discount_value' ~ customer_group.customer_group_id ? 'discount_value' ~ customer_group.customer_group_id : '' }}
```

it will return as a string, instead of variable.

In php it will return eg: `$discount_value1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `_context`  for this:

```
{% set discount_value = _context['discount_value' ~ customer_group.customer_group_id] is defined ? _context['discount_value' ~ customer_group.customer_group_id] : '' %}
```

and then echo `discount_value`